# Remove item from dropped area when item is dragged out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to be able to remove item from droppable list. User is able to drag and drop items into droppable area, and it prevents from duplicating same item. Now I want to remove item from the list by dragging out the item. How it can be done? Here is script im using:

```
        $(function () {
        $("#myAccordion").accordion({heightStyle:"content", active: false, collapsible:true});
        $("#myAccordion li").draggable({
                connectToSortable: '.container',
                helper: 'clone',
                create: function () {
                    var eq = $(this).index();
                    $(this).attr('data-index', eq);
                }
            });
        $(".container").sortable({
                connectWith: '.container',
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                receive: function (event, ui) {
                    var uiIndex = ui.item.attr('data-index');
                    var item =  $(this).find('[data-index=' + uiIndex + ']');
                    if (item.length > 1) {
                        item.last().remove();
                    }
                },
                revert: true
            });
        $(".container li").draggable({
                connectToSortable: '.container',
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                revert: true
            });
        });
```

And [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/montel388/bbthwfr2/1/)

Comment: stop posting question deleting and asking again same question

Comment: @guradio so please help me with question, so i dont need to ask it again